# Do Karaites have the Kabbalah?

Tags: mysticism-kabbalah, oral-torah, non-rabbinic-judaism

When studying the [Kabbalah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kabbalah#Origins) it is clear that the tradition of its wisdom did not start at Mount Sinai but dates back to the creation of the world ([a hint here](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Otzar_Midrashim%2C_Book_of_Rezial_the_Angel.1?vhe=Otzar_Midrashim,_New_York,_1915&lang=he)):

> וכתוב בשער הספר כי המלאך רזיאל מסר את הספר הזה לאדם הראשון אחר ק״ל שנה לתשובתו, והוא מסרו לנח ולשם ולאברהם וכו׳, עד שעמד שלמה המלך ונגלו לו ספר הרזים והרבה ספרים נמסרו בידו, וזה נמצא יקר ונכבד מכולם (דפוס אמשטרדם דף ל״ד ע״א).

As I understand, the Karaites did not accept ONLY the Rabbinical decrees, not "the whole oral Torah", after all, they do observe all the Mitzvos.

Do Karaite Jews have [some] the tradition of the Kabbalah?

*This is a factual question, not speculational, please don't answer if you don't really KNOW.*

Comment: It's clear because a book claims to be ancient?

Comment: Karaites accept many Rabbinic things. Synagogues, prescribed prayer, praying in accordance with Rabbinic rulings (that we have now abandoned). If Kabbalah was around when they broke off then they probably have it in some form. But more than likely it wasn't widely known during the time they split away from us

Comment: There were many Karaites historically that accepted some form of Kabbalah. It was undoubtedly under rabbinic influence. I am a karaite.